# TextBox Date Format in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, date, textbox

I want to use as a DatetimePicker. I want to validate for date format. i am using keypress event to validate. the following code is written in KeyPress event.

```
 DateTime temp;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out temp))
        { textBox1.Text = temp.ToShortDateString(); }
        else
        { errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Format dd/MM/yyyy"); }
```

but after entering date and month it automatically gives year also i don't want it like that.

User can enter full date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `LostFocus` or `Leave` event instead of the `KeyPress` event.

Answer (score 0):

TRY This Following Javascript Code : No Need .Net Implementation :

```
function isValidDate(date){
var matches = /^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{4})$/.exec(date);
if (matches == null) return false;
var d = matches[2];
var m = matches[1] - 1;
var y = matches[3];
var composedDate = new Date(y, m, d);
return composedDate.getDate() == d &&
        composedDate.getMonth() == m &&
        composedDate.getFullYear() == y;
}
console.log(isValidDate('10-12-1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('12/11/1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('02-11-1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('12/01/1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('13-11-1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('11-31-1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('11-31-1061'));
```

Use this Function onKeyPress Event. If Not Worked Comment.

Regards..

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        if(DateTime.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out dt))
        {textBox1.Text =dt.ToShortDateString();}
```

in Leave event it works fine...,